# jQuery: Add or Remove function in a specific window size

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinyscrollbar

I am very new to jQuery/JS and I have little problem with add or remove function in a specific window size.
I would appreciate if you can take a look at my code and correct it.

In detail, I use tinyscrollbar plugin that I want only appear in a specific window size(let's say above 650px of window width).

Here is my code:

```
<!--****preload latest jQuery and tinyscrollbar plugin, then...****-->

<script type="text/javascript">

function newsScroll() {
    $("#newsScroll").tinyscrollbar();
};

/*
if windows width is less than 650px, remove newsScroll function and
switch DIV ID to "spNewsScroll" and vice versa.
*/
function scrollOnOff(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if (width < 650) {
        $(window).unbind(newsScroll);
        $("#newsScroll").attr('id','spNewsScroll');
    } else {
        $(window).bind(newsScroll);
        $("#spNewsScroll").attr('id','newsScroll');
    }
};

$(function() {
    //get window size as of now.
    scrollOnOff($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        scrollOnOff($(this).width());
    });       
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [doco for `.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) - it expects an event type as its first parameter, with the callback function as its second or third parameter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, tested and working :-)

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/fUsnj/21/

```
function scrollOnOff(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    if(width < 650){
        $(window).trigger('newsScroll');
        $('#newsScroll').attr('id','spNewsScroll');
    } else {
        $('.scrollbar').hide();
        $('#spNewsScroll').attr('id','newsScroll');
    }
};

$(function() {

    $(window).bind('newsScroll', function(e) {
        $('.scrollbar').show();
        $('#newsScroll').tinyscrollbar();
    });

    var screenWidth = $(this).width();
    scrollOnOff(screenWidth);

    $(window).on("resize", function(event){
        var w = $(this).width();
        scrollOnOff(w);                
    });

});
```

​

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply, Oscar!
Although I implemented your suggestion, it doesn't seem to be working somehow. I created jsFiddle for this, would you take a look at the code?

1.tinyscrollbar is not loaded on page load.
2.When I change window size(drag center separator to change window size.)

http://jsfiddle.net/nori2tae/fUsnj/

(note. jQuery1.7.2 and tinyscrollbar.js is attached to this fiddle(http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/js/jquery.tinyscrollbar.min.js)).

Comment: Ok, let me take a look and let you know.

Comment: @norixxx try this: http://jsfiddle.net/oscarj24/fUsnj/21/ I will also update the post.

Comment: Oscar.It worked so fine! Thank you so much! I will study harder on JS/jQuery ;-)

Comment: @norixxx No problem, I am here to help :-) Don't forget to click the check image next to this post to select this as your answer. I am telling this cause you are new here :-)